# Accessing NATed HTTP server

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a HTTP server hosted on my android device. I want it to be able to access it from the internet even when it is connected on home wifi(behind a wireless router).

Further, configuring static port forwarding on router is not an option, since from the internet, I won't have access to the router configuration.

Do I have any option?

I tried this:

Android App sends a HTTP request from android device(with local IP address, say 192.168.0.1) from a particular port number(say 8080), to a web server on internet through home WIFI,

Router would modify the source address to that of its public IP address(say 111.100.45.65) and source port number to any random port number(say 39824) and makes an entry in its dynamic NAT table.

Internal IP     Internal port   External port
192.168.0.1 8080        39824

As per my understanding this entry is retained for atleast few hours.
Web server on the internet would report the source IP and port as 111.100.45.65 and 39824 respectively.

After sending the HTTP request from android app to web server on the internet, I run an HTTP server on port 8080 of the device. Now, if I were to send HTTP request from the internet to the address 111.100.45.65 at port 39824, it should be received by HTTP server running on device(router would resolve the request from its dynamic NAT table and direct it to my device).

But for some reason, this request doesn't get resolved. Any pointers.

Comment: You really want to use a VPN for this.

Comment: VPN too isn't an option. I am trying to achieve tcp hole punching. I am connecting to the public sever from a particular port on android(behind router). Also, I am listening in the other thread at the same port in my app. Shouldn't the thread be able to receive the HTTP request from the client on public server, since public server is now aware of router ip and port?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly regarding access to router configurations from the Internet, most routers do actually support logins from the WAN interface. It's turned off by default on most routers, but there is no reason why you can't enable this as long as your password is secure.

Secondly, what you tried would work if you setup a proxy on the web server on the Internet.

1. Punch a TCP hole by initiating connection from your Android device to the web server on the Internet.
2. Now the web server on the Internet knows the public IP and the destination port to be able to talk to the Android device.
3. An automated script can configure the proxy server on the web server on the Internet that will forward HTTP requests to the Android device.

By the way, I am doubtful that the NAT entry is retained for at least a few hours. You may wish to implement a keep-alive mechanism between your Android device and the web server on the Internet so that the TCP hole remains open.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Logging to router interface remotely is also not possible in my case. The HTTP server app is going to be installed on many users' devices, each connected to different WIFI network. As such, I won't have access to router credentials. Could you please elaborate on your 3rd point. Thanks again.

Comment: Once the hole is punched as "Android -> Router -> Web Server", the only thing that can talk to the Android device from the Internet is the host that has the same source IP address as the Web Server i.e. the Web Server itself and nothing else. Therefore if you want to talk to the Android device from other places on the Internet, you have to go VIA the Web Server i.e. the Web Server needs to act as a proxy.

Comment: The reason the Proxy needs to be configured dynamically is of course the public IP address (and port number) of the Android device changes. You could do this by: (1) Punch hole by HTTP request to a PHP file on the Web Server. (2) The PHP file automatically configures the proxy server on the server itself so that it will forward traffic from other places on the Internet received on a particular port to the Android device. Sorry, but I am unable to give you exact details on how exactly the PHP script will automatically configure the proxy server, but I am sure this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app can communicate over port 39824 with the http server on the web. Nobody else can use that port to make contact from web to your http server on your device.  You need portforwarding on your router for your device be reachable from internet.